# How to properly login to spotify?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, spotify

I have an application that allow user to stream song from spotify. I'm using swift here. I'm trying to allow user to login with spotify account, but I got nothing in return. My app did open safari in order to open spotify login page. I've done login but still returns nothing.

I've make sure that my **callbackuri** is exactly the same as in my spotify dev page, my url schemes is the first section before colon of my callback uri, and my otherlinker is filled with **-ObjC**

Here is what I've tried

login action:

```
    let spotifyAuth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
    spotifyAuth.clientID = kSpotifyClientID
    spotifyAuth.redirectURL = NSURL(string: kSpotifyCallBackUrl)
    spotifyAuth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]

    let spotifyLoginUrl : NSURL = spotifyAuth.loginURL

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(spotifyLoginUrl)
```

my appdelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool{

    println("rene jos1")
    if (SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandleURL(url)) {


        println("rene jos2")

        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, callback: { (error : NSError?, session : SPTSession?) -> Void in


            println("rene jos3")
            if error != nil {

                println("Auth error : \(url.description)")
                return
            }

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(session!)
            userDefaults.setObject(sessionData, forKey: "spotifySession")

            userDefaults.synchronize()

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("spotifyLoginSuccesfull", object: nil)

       })

        return true
    }

    if (FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)) {

        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

and my viewdidload:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateAfterFirstlogin", name: "spotifyLoginSuccesfull", object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    spotifyLoginButton.hidden = true

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let sessionObj : AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("spotifySession") {
         println("rene 2")

        let sessionDataObj : NSData = sessionObj as! NSData
        let session = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
        self.playUsingSession(session)

        if !session.isValid() {

            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(session, callback: { (error : NSError!, newsession : SPTSession!) -> Void in

                let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(session)
                userDefaults.setObject(sessionData, forKey: "spotifySession")
                userDefaults.synchronize()

                self.session = newsession

                self.playUsingSession(newsession)
                println("rene 3")
            })
        }else{

            println("error refreshing new spotify session")

        }

    }else{

        spotifyLoginButton.hidden = false
         println("rene 4")

    }
```

So, Am I missing something?
Any suggestion would be great

Comment: What print statement does it get up to?

Comment: @myles I got >> Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=8 "Login to Spotify failed because of invalid credentials." UserInfo=0x7f840bf807b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Login to Spotify failed because of invalid credentials.}

Answer (score 0):

make sure your callback uri is all lowercase letters, I had issues with that.